# Running external Ant file from a parent pom

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I would like to run an Ant `build.xml` build from a parent POM.

This may look like this:

```
<project>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <ant antfile="build.xml"/>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This works just fine unless I use this module as a parent POM.
The problem is in this line `<ant antfile="build.xml"/>`. While this POM is running as a parent POM there is no `build.xml` file available to the plugin.

How can I run an Ant script *from a file* (located in the parent POM) during all child build?

PS
I tried to package the `build.xml` under some classifier to make it available to the children builds. But I have no idea, how can I extract my packaged `build.xml` prior to the `antrun:run`.

PPS

The project structure:

```
<root>
  + Parent POM
  | +- pom.xml
  | +- build.xml
  |
  + Component1
  | + Child1
  | | +- src/main/java
  | | +- ...
  | | +- pom.xml
  | |
  | + Child2
  |   +- src/main/java
  |   +-...
  |   +- pom.xml
  |
  + Component2
    + Child3
    | +- src/main/java
    | +- ...
    | +- pom.xml
    |
    + Child4
      +- src/main/java
      +-...
      +- pom.xml
```

As a bonus: I also would like to know the answer for the situations, where the parent POM get built and deployed independently (not knowing own child) and children get built having only access to the parent deployed artifacts (not the source code).

Comment: Okay. So are you running Maven from the root project? And could you post the whole stacktrace, if there is one?

Comment: I'm running my build from both: root and children directories. The exception I get is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: <root>\Component1\Child2\build.xml`

Comment: What do you mean from both? Normally, you should run `mvn clean install` from `<root>` only.

Comment: My project I quite big, so developers run `mvn clean install` from root only after changing branch or checkout. It takes ~15 minutes. Most often a build get triggered from a ChildX directory.

Comment: `mvn clean install` for a multi module build is usually the wrong way...second if you want to speed up your build use: `mvn -pl TheModuleYouWouldLikeToBuild -amd clean package` ...Apart from that have you tried to use `mvn -T 4 clean package`? Furthermore why do you need an Ant part? Waht is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the `FileNotFoundException` you could use a configured property as prefix of the ant build file. Such a property would be empty on the parent pom while would have the right prefix (i.e. relative path to parent folder) in the required modules.

For instance, in your parent POM your configuration would look like:

```
<properties>
    <ant.build.dir.prefix></ant.build.dir.prefix>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <ant antfile="${ant.build.dir.prefix}build.xml" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note the `${ant.build.dir.prefix}` prefix added to the ant invocation. By default it will be empty, which means file would be supposed to be located in the same directory as the pom.

However, in modules you would just need to override the value of the property, as following:

```
<properties>
    <ant.build.dir.prefix>..\</ant.build.dir.prefix>
</properties>
```

Or any other relative path in the folders hierarchy.

At runtime, the value will be replaced and as such the path to the ant file will dynamically change, enforcing a common and centralized configuration of the ant run (in the parent pom) and a specific path configuration in modules (via a property prefix).

I just tested both cases (your configuration and the prefixed one) in a sample project with an echo ant task, being able to reproduce your issue and to fix it as suggested above.

Comment: @BorisBrodski did this help?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know for sure. I ended up using https://github.com/jdcasey/directory-maven-plugin plugin, since it gave me way more flexibility and was easier to configure.