# Best practice in deploying a parent pom with "supporting files" (ie an external ant file)

Tags: maven, ant, parent-pom

I have a parent pom, deployed to my local artifactory server. This is a parent to several War projects. It uses maven ant run plugin and runs Ant targets defined in an external file called pombuild.xml like this:

```
<execution>
    <id>compile</id>
    <phase>deploy</phase>
    <configuration>
        <target if="project.is.war">
        <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
        <ant antfile="${ant.file}" target="compileJsp"/>
        </target>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
       <goal>run</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

The ant.file property is defined as

```
<ant.file>${user.home}/.m2/repository/${pom.parent.groupId}/${pom.parent.artifactId}/${pom.parent.version}/pombuild.xml</ant.file>
```

So I am looking for a way to have maven automatically download pombuild.xml at the same location as the parent pom.

The question is : Is this possible?  And if so, is this best practice?  Should I be doing it differently?

Some may say that my problem has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120490/running-external-ant-file-from-a-parent-pom) but this is not exactly what I want.

Comment: Defining something like antrun in the parent of a project is against any best practice apart from using antrun plugin...sounds like you are doing something wrong...I don't understand why are you doing such things? To deploy things in Maven simply a `mvn deploy` is needed. If you have war packaging everything should work if you need such configuration my assumption is you are doing something wrong...

Comment: This is a conversion from an Ant Project to a Maven project.  The ant script calls WebLogic's JSP compilation.  We couldn't precompile the jsps using the weblogic maven plugins so we opted to use the ant approach which works

Comment: The JSP will be compiled during the first access to the pages...like Tomcat, JBoss etc. does...I wouldn't do that during the build...If it does not work with weblogic-maven-plugin I assume you did something wrong...Or the plugin is buggy...Do you really need this?

Comment: Oh no!  You can't just deploy the JSPs and wait for the container to compile them on first access and HOPE THAT EVERYTHING IS OK. You have to compile all JSPS **before** you deploy to production, to make sure that there are no compilation errors.  And of course I am  not doing this during the build (That would considerably  slow down the build) .

Comment: Don't you have unit- and integration tests to make sure everything is working ? So you have deployed to other stages before after this you can deploy to production.....